# AWS Step function error : There are Amazon States Language errors in your state machine definition. Fix the errors to continue

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-step-functions

I'm new to AWS step functions.
Trying to create a basic ETL flow of glue jobs. Upon completion of state machine definition im able to see the graph being generated , but getting a generic error "There are Amazon States Language errors in your state machine definition. Fix the errors to continue",
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev0jO.png)
that is not allowing me to proceed.

Here is the code and graph :

```
{
  "Comment": "DRC downstream glue jobs execution step function:slf_aws_can_dbisdel_everyone_drc_amp",
  "StartAt": "startFlow",
  "States": {
    "Comment": "various state types of the Amazon States Language",
    "startFlow": {
      "Comment": "Pass states are useful when constructing and debugging state machines.",
      "Type": "Pass",
      "Next": "stg_ods"
    },
    "stg_ods": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "stage_job_name"
      },
      "Next": "ods_job"
    },
    "ods_job": {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
      "Parameters": {
        "JobName": "main_job_name"
      },
      "Next": "Wait 3 sec"
    },    
    "Wait 3 sec": {
      "Comment": "A Wait state delays the state machine from continuing for a specified time.",
      "Type": "Wait",
      "Seconds": 3,
      "Next": "parallel_stg_adr"
    },
    "parallel_stg_adr": {
      "Comment": "A Parallel state can be used to create parallel branches of execution in your state machine.",
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "stg_job1",
          "States": {
            "stg_job1": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "JobName": "stg_job_name1"
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "stg_job2",
          "States": {
            "stg_job2": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "JobName": "stg_job_name2"
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "Next": "parallel_adr_job"
    },
    "parallel_adr_job": {
      "Comment": "A Parallel state can be used to create parallel branches of execution in your state machine.",
      "Type": "Parallel",
      "Branches": [
        {
          "StartAt": "job1",
          "States": {
            "job1": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "JobName": "some_glue_job",
                "Arguments": {
                  "--target_table": "some_string_table",
                  "--calendar_key": "some_string"
                }
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "StartAt": "job2",
          "States": {
            "job2": {
              "Type": "Task",
              "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun.sync",
              "Parameters": {
                "JobName": "some_glue_job",
                "Arguments": {
                  "--target_table": "some_string_table",
                  "--calendar_key": "some_string"
                }
              },
              "End": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "Next": "end_job"
    },
    "end_job": {
      "Type": "Pass",
      "End": true
    }
  }
}
```

[Step function graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ccRvM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Comment": "various state types of the Amazon States Language",

This one at Line 5 seems to be incorrect. "States" map cannot have a "Comment" key. Remove it and then try. Rest of the config looks correct.

**Edit 1**

If the type of Step Function is Express, ".sync" functions won't work. Try changing the ARN to

```
"Resource": "arn:aws:states:::glue:startJobRun"
```

and you should be able to save your Step Function. You will then have to figure out how to setup a different Glue task.

Comment: You are correct regarding "Comment" key, Note i'm getting error while creating Express state machine , when i put in corrected code in Standard machine it doesn't throw any error.

Comment: Got it. ".sync"  function won't be supported for Express Step Functions. I've updated the answer.